# How to use Rsqlite to save and load data in sqlite

Tags: r, sqlite, dataframe

I am learning SQLite and I have a big data frame in csv format and I imported into the SQLite.

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="myDB.sqlite")
dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = "myDB", dataframe, overwrite=T,
         row.names=FALSE)
```

after that, I saw there is a myDB.sqlite in my directory but with zero byte. How can I save the dataframe in the sqlite so that I don't need to write table everytime. Thanks.

Comment: Your Code works fine for me. If you wan't to make sure that you are just appending and not overwriting set `overwrite=F` and `append=T`. The reason it says zero bytes is because R's file viewer doesn't auto refresh when you change a file.

Comment: @calder.ty how can i save it in sqlite db? I want to load it from the db next time . thanks if u can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be written in your db. Like i said before, your code works for me it's just that the R-Studio File Viewer doesn't automatically Refresh when some of the files have been written to.

Just to be sure that data was written to your db try running this `dbGetQuery(conn=db, "SELECT * FROM myDB)`. That should return your data frame.